# Install WSL2 on 18363 fails despite official docs say it should work

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The [official docs here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#update-to-wsl-2) say WSL2 works from build 18362 or greater.

> Running Windows 10, updated to version 1903 or higher, Build 18362 or higher for x64 systems.

I've got: 1836**3**

```sh
WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | % Buildnumber
18363
```

System information shows the same:

[image]

The required features are enabled:

```sh
C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux"


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
DisplayName      : Windows Subsystem for Linux
Description      : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
                   ServerComponent\Description : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux
                   shells and tools on Windows.
                   ServerComponent\DisplayName : Windows Subsystem for Linux
                   ServerComponent\Id : 1033
                   ServerComponent\Type : Feature
                   ServerComponent\UniqueName : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
                   ServerComponent\Deploys\Update\Name : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux




C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "VirtualMachinePlatform"


FeatureName      : VirtualMachinePlatform
DisplayName      : Virtual Machine Platform
Description      : Enables platform support for virtual machines
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
```

[image]

However, when I run

```sh
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

I'm getting:

```sh
C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --set-default-version 2
Invalid command line option: --set-default-version
```

Any idea what I've missed?

Comment: It might be easiest to update Windows to a newer version. From what I saw, V1909 or later.  V2004 is stable now.

Comment: @John yes and no. I'm not getting the new version through windows update yet and I usually don't enforce updates because I don't trust it enough to not screw something up when it doesn't tell me it's ready. So forcing an update is not an option for me. I'll wait until KB4566116 leaves its current preview state and is distributed through windows update.

Answer (score 1):

WSL is definitely available on my Production V2004 System (and Insider as well).

[image]

Comment: WSL2 was also released to 1903 and 1909 on August 20 with the release of the KB4566116 cumulative update.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea what I've missed?

In order to use WSL2 on 1903 or 1909 the minor build must be greater or equal to 1049.  On September 8th 2020, [KB4574727](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4574727) was released which increases the minor build to 1082, installing this required security cumulative update will enable WSL2 functionality on 1903 and 1909.

> The first number before the . is your major build number, so for version 1903 this will read 18362. The number after the . is your minor build number, and this will let you know whether you have the backport on your machine. This backport has the minor build number: 1049. To summarize, if your minor build number is 1049 or higher on Windows builds 18362 or 18363, then you have the backport and the ability to run WSL 2 distros.

> [image]

Source: [WSL 2 Support is coming to Windows 10 Versions 1903 and 1909](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-support-is-coming-to-windows-10-versions-1903-and-1909/)

However, your only two options other than installing this patch is to wait for the next cumulative update to be released or manually upgrade to 2004 with the [Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3159635/windows-10-update-assistant) Tool.

Comment: KB4574727 was the current stable cumlative update when I submitted this answer.  The minor build of 1909 and 1903 must be greater than 1049 in order to have this backport functionality.

Answer (score -2):

That document is in error or was too optimistic.
WSL2 was only announced in
[WSL 2 is now available in Windows Insiders](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-is-now-available-in-windows-insiders/):

> We’re excited to announce starting today you can try the Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 by installing Windows build 18917 in the Insider Fast ring

Build 18917 is an Insider preview to Windows 10 version 2004, but the release
version is already available as build 19041.

So you need to upgrade to Windows 10 version 2004 in order to have WSL2.

Although WSL2 is currently also being back-ported to earlier version
of Windows 10, this is still a work in progress.
If the update is not showing up in Windows Update, this means that it's
not yet verified for your configuration.
It would be more prudent in this case to update to Windows 10 version 2004
(which is a good idea in any case).

Comment: @harrymc I think you're wrong, the article is right but fails to mention that you have to install an update that is in *preview* state and has not yet been released for 19041. So you have to manually download and install it. https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4566116 I already created a ticket for the docs and reported that it is missing that piece of information.

Comment: @burzum - 19041 is 2004 not 1903 or 1909 so the update I was referring to isn’t applicable to 19041