# Windows 10 WSL1 seems already installed, how to configure?

Tags: linux, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Just for fun I typed `bash` in a command window, and much to my surprise it started up. It was surprising because I never installed WSL1, and docs like the install guide from Microsoft imply that you have to.  It's possible I installed some other Linix subsystem years ago, but I don't remember doing so.

I do not have the W10 version necessary to run WSL2 (mine is 18362.1082), so if it's WSL it must be WSL1. Other than that, I have no idea what flavor or version of Linux it is. I tried the normal linux command for this purpose like cat /etc/os-release, which replies there is no such file.

The docs say that the linux admin credentials are independent of the W10 credentials. So I also ran `whoami` to see if a user had been established and it gave me the same name as for my W10 installation. When I tried to use a `sudo` command to see if it was the same password too, it said `bash: sudo: command not found`. So something is amiss.

How can I determine what I have here? How can I tell if this is a WSL1 instance that is fully set up and if so what flavor/version of Linux it's running? Also what the admin password is? Or do I still need to take all the steps in the install guide linked above?

Update 1

I found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) that I should be able to launch wsl by entering `wsl` on a command line. When I do so it says wsl is not recognized as a command, so I suppose this means wsl1 is not installed.  There is some linux installed though, so the question now is whether it's safe to install wsl1 over that or if I need to uninstall the existing first (and if so how to do that).

Comment: Make sure you have a current version of Windows, open Control Panel, Programs and Features, Windows Features, scroll down to the bottom and enable Windows Subsytem for Linux.  Close out, restart and WSL should be there.

Comment: @John, so there is no need to worry about whatever is installed already?  I suspect this got installed along with powershell a couple years ago.  Also once I enable WSL I install the linux distribution of my choice as described here? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: I am not sure at this point. You might remove WSL (Windows Features) , make sure no VMware products are installed, restart the computer and the enable WSL via Windows Features, do a final restart and test again.

Comment: I did enable WSL on the features dialog and reboot.  If I enter wsl -l it still says wsl is not recognized as a command.  Tried with admin access, but same result.  Does it need a path, maybe?  IDK if this means I need to go through the install process, or if there would be any harm doing so if it's already installed.

Comment: Try the following:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator . Run  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  and then  SFC /SCANNOW  When complete Restart and test.

Comment: Worked!  It's now telling me to install a distro.  Thanks!

Comment: "I do not have the W10 version necessary to run WSL2 (mine is 18362.1082)" - [You actually could use WSL2 on your installation.](https://superuser.com/questions/1583272/install-wsl2-on-18363-fails-despite-official-docs-say-it-should-work/1583479#1583479).  You don't have to uninstall WSL to use any VMWare products.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have some Bash somewhere doesn’t mean you have WSL installed.

First, you should check where `bash` is actually located:

```
where bash
```

Or, in PowerShell:

```
Get-Command bash
```

Unless you get `C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe`, it’s most likely not WSL but something different like Git Bash, MinGW32 or whatnot.

To use WSL, you need to install a distribution in addition to enabling the Windows Feature. You’d remember something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> I found here that I should be able to launch wsl by entering wsl on a command line. When I do so it says wsl is not recognized as a command, so I suppose this means wsl1 is not installed. There is some linux installed though, so the question now is whether it's safe to install wsl1 over that or if I need to uninstall the existing first (and if so how to do that).

This does indeed mean you don't have the optional `Windows Subsystem for Linux` currently installed

> The docs say that the linux admin credentials are independent of the W10 credentials. So I also ran whoami to see if a user had been established and it gave me the same name as for my W10 installation. When I tried to use a sudo command to see if it was the same password too, it said bash: sudo: command not found.

This is also an indication that the Linux bash shell (i.e. `Windows Subsystem for Linux`) is not actually installed on your system.  You can determine which bash environment you actually have installed by looking at the process name within Task Manager.

> I do not have the W10 version necessary to run WSL2 (mine is 18362.1082), so if it's WSL it must be WSL1. Other than that, I have no idea what flavor or version of Linux it is. I tried the normal Linux command for this purpose like cat /etc/os-release, which replies there is no such file.

You absolutely can run WSL2 since you are running 18362.1049+ (1903) or 18363.1049+ (1909).  WSL1 and WSL2 are both fully compatible with the current versions of VMWare virtualization products.

> The first number before the . is your major build number, so for version 1903 this will read 18362. The number after the . is your minor build number, and this will let you know whether you have the backport on your machine. This backport has the minor build number: 1049. To summarize, if your minor build number is 1049 or higher on Windows builds 18362 or 18363, then you have the backport and the ability to run WSL 2 distros.

Sources:

- [WSL 2 Support is coming to Windows 10 Versions 1903 and 1909](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-support-is-coming-to-windows-10-versions-1903-and-1909/)
- [Install WSL2 on 18363 fails despite official docs say it should work](https://superuser.com/questions/1583272/install-wsl2-on-18363-fails-despite-official-docs-say-it-should-work/1583479#1583479)